# Return HTML from URL into SQL Server (T-SQL)

Tags: html, sql-server, t-sql, html-email, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which uses some logic to determine if there's a particular problem which needs reporting, then uses `sp_send_dbmail` to email the relevant group to alert them to this. The stored procedure is scheduled to run every 15 minutes via a SQL Server Agent Job.

There is some information contained on a non-static webpage which I would like to include in the body of the email, but I realise I cannot use an iframe to embed this content within my email as most email clients do not allow iframes.

Is there any way for me to fetch the HTML from a URL in real-time when the stored procedure is run, so that I can append this HTML to the `@body` parameter of `sp_send_dbmail`?

Comment: What would be the content and formatting in @body?

Comment: I am currently setting the `@body_format` parameter of `sp_send_dbmail` to 'HTML', so the content of `@body` is HTML code. Essentially, if I could make a call within SQL where I supply a URL and the return is a varchar (or similar) containing the HTML for the page at that URL (as it would appear if I inspected it through a browser - say with View Source or Dev Tools - visiting the same URL), that would be ideal.